# 'Unquoted string ".." may clash with future reserved word' but only when package is used

Tags: perl

I ran into this problem while trying to refactor one of my modules into object oriented code. I narrowed it down to the following. Here is the listing for the 3 files I am using:

_mypkg.pm:

```
use _debug;
use _debug dprint;
package mypkg;
sub new {
   my($class,%args) = @_;
   my $self = bless {}, $class;
   dprint "pkg<br>\n";
   return $self;
}
1;
```

_debug.pm:

```
# package mydebug; # uncommenting this line gives error 500
my $bprint = "";
sub print_now   { print "printing: ".$bprint; $bprint = "";}
sub bprint  { $bprint .= "@_"; }
sub dprint  {  bprint @_;  }
1;
```

testfile.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require '_mypkg.pm';
#require '_debug.pm';
#use _debug;
use _debug dprint;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
dprint "first<br>\n";
&print_now;
my $somepkg = mypkg->new();
dprint "second<br>\n";
&print_now;
```

As they appear above, there is no output, but commenting out the lines:

```
require '_mypkg.pm';
my $somepkg = mypkg->new();
```

in testfile.cgi, leads to the following (expected) output:

```
printing: first
printing: second
```

Running the script (without modifications) with -w leads to the following output in the error logs (trimmed a bit for clarity):

```
Unquoted string "dprint" may clash with future reserved word
Unquoted string "mypkg" may clash with future reserved word
String found where operator expected at _mypkg.pm, near "dprint "pkg<br>\\n""
\t(Do you need to predeclare dprint?)
syntax error at _mypkg.pm line 10, near "dprint "pkg<br>\\n""
Compilation failed in require
```

Basically, I want to use dprint (which is defined in _debug.pm) to replace "print" in my scripts.. (ie, without parentheses or an &) and it has worked perfectly until I tried using it in modules where I began trying to use objects.. ie, "package". So, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few problems with your code, some of which I'm not sure are typos or not, for example, in your file `_mypkg.pm` you have `package mypkg;` instead of `package _mypkg;`.

Here is a cleaned up version - have a careful look at the differences, consulting [perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/) if you need. You should also get in to the habit of putting `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your script, and in a cgi environment `use CGI::Carp('fatalsToBrowser');` can be invaluable when testing.

_mypkg.pm

```
package _mypkg;
use _debug qw(dprint); # import dprint()

sub new {
    my($class,%args) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    dprint "pkg<br>\n";
    return $self;
}
1;
```

_debug.pm

```
package _debug;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(print_now dprint);

my $bprint = "";
sub print_now   { print "printing: ".$bprint; $bprint = "";}
sub bprint  { $bprint .= "@_"; }
sub dprint  {  bprint @_;  }
1;
```

testfile.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use _mypkg;
use _debug qw(print_now dprint); # import print_now() and dprint()

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
dprint "first<br>\n";
print_now;
my $somepkg = _mypkg->new();
print_now;
dprint "second<br>\n";
print_now;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I did have use strict and use warnings, I just didn't want to include it above for brevity, and because they didn't contribute to the problem. Also, I had read in the docs that the package name and module name don't have to be the same, so that also wasn't contributing to the problem either. The two lines that begin with "use Exporter" along with moving the package declaration in _mypkg.pm (given @mob's answer) are what solved it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In `_mypkg.pm`, you call `use _debug;` before the `package mypkg;` declaration. That means that Perl reads the `_debug.pm` file in the default namespace (`main`), and the `print_now`, `bprint`, and `dprint` subroutines are defined in the `main` namespace.

The `mypkg::new` subroutine is defined after the `package mypkg;` statement, and so its definition takes place in the `mypkg` namespace. There is no `dprint` function defined in that namespace, so Perl chokes on the line

```
dprint "pkg<br>\n";
```

The fix is to switch the order of the `use` and `package` statements:

_mypkg.pm:

```
package mypkg;
use _debug;
use _debug dprint;
...
```

This will define the `dprint` function in the correct namespace (`mypkg`).

Comment: thanks for the answer! Your explanation is exactly what I needed to understand what was going on. I still needed to add the "use Exporter" lines suggested in @tangent's answer for it to work (unless you can explain a way for me to solve this without it). So the solution was a mix of both your answers. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to mark your answer as useful, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.